# One Thread Per Subscriber

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using roscpp, and I am programmatically creating a bunch of subscriber callbacks (using `ShapeShifter`). Each callback is not computationally expensive, but I'm measuring the difference between the published time in the header, and the received time. As such, the first line of my callback defines the received time.

So having a single threaded model isn't great, because one subscriber callback will block another callback, and increase its lag time.

Ideally I'd like to create one thread per subscriber. I can't use a custom callback queue, because these are not called by `ros::spin`.

So what is the most idiomatic way to have each subscriber run on its own thread?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226759/one-thread-per-subscriber/) by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does `ros::MultiThreadedSpinner` not already do what you describe? See [roscpp - Overview - Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

---

Edit: you might also be interested in the topic statistics support added in Indigo. See [Topics - Topic statistics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics) and [rosprofiler](http://wiki.ros.org/rosprofiler).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [solb22](https://answers.ros.org/users/25924/solb22/) on 2016-02-16**:
Hm, I guess it does, is there a limit to the number of thread I can pass to that? The documentation made it look like I was limited to the number of cores on my machine. I was actually looking at `ros::AsyncSpinner`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-16**:
Both the wiki page and the [API documentation](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1MultiThreadedSpinner.html) state:

> You can specify a number of threads in its constructor, but if unspecified (or set to 0), it will use a thread for each CPU core.

Num cpus is only default

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-16**:
Same applies to `AsyncSpinner`.